# PHP curl get multidimensional array

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm trying to get a list of issues using gitlab API. The response is correct testing the URL, but the curl doesnot execute in my php code. I guess it`s because of the multidimensional array. but how do you solve this? Here is my function:

```
function getissues_list () {

    $url = MAIN_URL."/issues";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET , true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->token);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!curl_exec($ch)) {

        echo ($this->exception_message);

    } else{
        return $response;
        curl_close($ch);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the response of `print_r($response);` and `print_r(curl_error($ch));`

Comment: Could not resolve host: MAIN_URL // Could not initialize curl session!

Comment: Just make sure your `MAIN_URL."/issues"` is correct

Comment: Actually cant concatenate the const and the second part for some reason...

Comment: Can you do `print_r(MAIN_URL)`  and the share the result

Answer (score 0):

```
function getissues_list () {
    global MAIN_URL; // Is this accessible in this function?

    $url = MAIN_URL."/issues";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET , true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->token);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($response);// ADD THIS LINE TO DEBUG!!!!!!!!

    if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
        echo ($this->exception_message);
    } else{
        return $response;
        curl_close($ch);
    }

}
```

Comment: Added the line right before if statement and the result is bool(false). Otherwise it just executes the code in if statement. Forgot to mention that this piece of code works with another url which returns a single array...